# On average, how many overhauls will thrust reversers have in their lifetime?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, thrust-reverser

How many overhauls will a wide body aircraft composite thrust reverser undergo in its life? (not including damage, etc.)

Comment: That is an oddly specific question -- care to elaborate on what prompted you to ask? I don't recall any recent crashes or incidents linked to thrust reversers.

Comment: @Johnny I recall [at least one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lauda_Air_Flight_004), although not recently.

Answer (score 1):

The answer varies from aircraft to aircraft. The newer varities such as the A380 go for a overhaul in about 1200-1500 hours, whereas the B777's go once in 1600-2000 hours of service.When an aircraft goes to overhaul, only then the thrust reversers go to overhaul, because they are an important component of the engine of modern day aircrafts. Though we do not know when will an aircraft retire, so it i difficult to come at a concrete result. But, talking about B747, many airlines are retiring them at the age of 40 years. So, 40 years = 350400 hours. 350400/2000 = 175(Approx.) So, for a B747 the answer should be like 175, and this does not necessarily implies to other aircrafts as well.

Comment: do you have any source for this data?

Comment: Its from Wikipedia's time between overhaul article. Then I know that B747 are retiring at the age of 40. And calculations are from MS windows calculator!